# Removing/cutting beam beneath half-landing stairs

Tags: stairs, cutting, beam

I have half-landing stairs which go up 7 steps, around a flat bit, then up another 7 steps. The second portion of the steps is at the back of one of the downstairs rooms, and is currently boxed-in, with storage below. We are hoping to open up the full area beneath the stairs to install a downstairs WC, however there is a pretty substantial timber (~150 x 60 mm) running across the bottom of the boxed-in section.

Any ideas if it would be alright to cut this timber to place a doorway to a WC?

At the moment all I’ve done is chiselled away some plasterboard to see what is going on.

Cheers,
Dave[image]

Comment: I suspect that you drawing is incorrect. The stair stringers are probably supported by the joist you want to cut, and they don't run past like that. You'll need to verify that.

Comment: Yes you’re right, the joist goes all the way from wall to wall and the stairs sit on top.

Comment: There's your answer, then. One option might be to frame a wall under the stringer bearing point, essentially boxing off a small part of the area under the stairs.

Comment: It’s about too low for a functioning WC though. If I were to remove half the joist I guess I could support the remaining joist and stairs with an upright?